# Why do Rust's sort methods allocate memory?

Tags: sorting, rust, dynamic-allocation

Methods like [`sort_by`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/trait.MutableSliceAllocating.html#tymethod.sort_by) on `std::slice::MutableSliceAllocating` or [`sort_by`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.sort_by) on `collections::vec::Vec` are documented to *"allocate approximately 2 * n, where n is the length"*. I don't think that good C++ [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) implementations allocate (on the heap) and yet they accomplish the same O(n log n) complexity. Although, the Rust sort methods are stable unlike the C++ std::sort.

Why do the Rust sort methods allocate? To me, it doesn't fit the *"zero cost abstraction"* bill advertised [here](http://www.rust-lang.org).

Comment: The `sort_by` you reference is stable, so you should compare it with cpp's [stable sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort), which does allocate memory to achieve a lower complexity.

Comment: @aochagavia, Oh, I didn't know that (and didn't bother to check). Is there an unstable sort function in the Rust standard library then?

Comment: I don't know :/... I wouldn't be surprised if there is no standard unstable sort, because the language hasn't reached 1.0. Maybe you could submit a PR!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in the comment, this is a stable sort, which requires O(n) space to execute. The best O(n log n) stable sort, mergesort, requires about ½n temporary items. (I'm not familiar with Rust, so I don't know why it needs four times that.)

Stable sort can be achieved in O(log n) space, but only by [mergesort variant](http://pdf.aminer.org/001/025/671/practical_in_place_mergesort.pdf) that takes O(n log² n) time.

Answer (score 8):

I realise this is an old post, but I found it on google and the popular answer is wrong. It is in fact possible to perform a stable in-place sort using O(1) (not even log) memory and worst-case O(nlogn) time. See for example GrailSort or WikiSort.